# Need a live PHP editor like dreamweaver

Tags: php, ide

I am in need of a **live editing software** for `PHP` like there is `DreamVeawer` for `CSS`. I need the functionality that I can **select items** from the webpage and it will **highlight** the particular **source code** for it. If anyone knows about such a software please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? PHP can't output GUI-elements by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has a nifty add-on called Web Developer. You can't edit the PHP code directly because it's server side but you can highlight/edit the resulting HTML. You can find it here https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

Answer (score 1):

Use google chrome's webkit inspector, it will find you the right html source code, which you can then trace back to the PHP code.

Comment: +1 but if you arent actually debugging webkit rendering Firebug is much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you won't find a solution for that.

PHP runs on the server-side and doesn't render any code to the browser like HTML does.

The closest you'll come is selecting DOM elements in Firebug/Dreamweaver(or any other designy IDE) rendered after the PHP is parsed

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what youre looking for exactly. If you want a WYSIWYG html editor they are plenty.

If youre tring to trace function and method calls in code then you need an IDE with code assist. Both Eclipse and Netbeans with their respective PHP plugins have this - i.e. you click on a function call and it opens the file containing that function. Depending on the context this can also work with variables...

I think there are also WYSIWYG html plugins for both but im not sure as i dont use them.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you want but this IDE can give a help

Aptana http://www.aptana.com/
or
PHPStorm http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/